# How to add a max width Row inside a Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, layout

I'm trying to add a row inside a wrap widget. I want the row widget to span the entire width of its parent, and its content aligned to the right. The problem is that the row always wraps its content instead of spanning the entire width of its parent, therefore I cannot align the content of the row to the right.

```
Wrap( 
direction: Axis.vertical,
spacing: 5,
children: [
Container(width:_variableWidth, height:3, color:Colors.red,),
child: Text("Main Text") ),
Row(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
children:[ Text("Right"), ])
])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `Expanded` widget.

Wrap your `Text` widget with an `Expanded` Widget.

Sample :

```
      Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child : Text("Right",textAlign : TextAlign.right),
            color: Colors.amber,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work for me. First the layout must be inside a column and second the Expanded widget throws errors.